# Infinite loop in iterative preorder traversal of BST

Tags: c

I am trying to iteratively traverse a BST in preorder, but this function is getting stuck in an infinite loop while printing. Could someone please tell me why this is happening?

```
1 typedef struct node_{
2     int data;
3     struct node_* left;
4     struct node_* right;
5 }BST; 

22 void preorder(BST* tree){
23     if(tree==NULL){
24         return;
25     }
26     // create stack 
27     stack* stack=create_stack();
28     // push data onto stack
29     push(stack,tree->data);
30     while(isEmpty(stack)==0){
31         struct node_ *node;
32         node->data=top(stack);
33         printf("%d ",node->data);
34         // pop value off stack
35         pop(stack);
36         if(node->right!=NULL){
37             //push right child onto stack
38             push(stack,node->right->data);
39         }
40         if(node->left!=NULL){
41             // push left child onto stack
42             push(stack,node->left->data);
43         }
44     }
45 }
```

Comment: Did I answer this question to your satisfaction?

Answer (score 1):

Your loop never ends because `node->right` and `node->left` point to random memory locations. What is the value of `node`? You haven't assigned anything to it. Its value is random.

Another problem is that you're pushing `tree->data` onto the stack. You actually want to push `tree` onto the stack. Then you can pop a node off the stack and assign it to `node`. Now you can print `node->data` and check the children of `node`.

Comment: Ok I malloced space for the size of BST since that is what that structure was renamed to. My push function is expecting an integer which is why I had tree->data. The loop is no longer infinite, but only runs once. Any ideas?

Comment: In order to traverse the tree, you must push nodes onto the stack. Don't try to solve this problem by pushing data onto the stack. Preorder traversal means that you print the data at the current node, then recursively descend to the children. How do you recursively descend to the children? By pushing them onto the stack. On the next iteration of the loop, you pop a node off the stack. It must be a node. The data won't help you. If you don't have a node on the stack, you don't know where you are in the tree.